# SQL extract pattern from string with RegExp

Tags: sql, regex, mariadb

I am currently trying to extract a pattern from a string using MySQL but unfortunately did not manage to achieve the aspired result yet. Therefore I would love to get some support from you.

The string looks like this:

> AB3530A/AB476-1

I want to extract only this part:

> AB476

I already tried the following RegExp:

```
[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}
```

which returned:

> AB476-

I also tried:

```
[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}([^0-9]|$)
```

which returned `AB353` and `AB476` at http://regexr.com/ but only returns `AB353` in MariaDB.

Does anybody know how to only extract without any additional signs?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards

Comment: MySQL doesn't support that. All you can do is to match an expression with a pattern. And that's it. Read more on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: Have a look at this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: I am using the function REGEXP_SUBSTR which returns a string. That works fine. I just did not manage to return the right string.

Comment: @ShortDive That function doesn't exist in MySQL. Are you sure you are using MySQL? Aren't you using MariaBD or something else?

Comment: For clarification: I am using MariaDB and MySQL workbench. MariaDB supports the function REGEXP_SUBSTR: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/regexp_substr/. I just did not manage to return the right string yet. Therefore my RegExp needs to be modified but I don't know how.

Comment: @ShortDive Then change your tags! Why do you have MySQL there? Use [tag:mariadb]!

Comment: Sorry, I just changed it.

Comment: How do you get `AB353` to match with the regexr? http://regexr.com/3eub4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pcre) shows that since its version 10.0.5, MariaDB supports Perl compatible regexp (“PCRE”).

This construct should then work `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(`*your_string*`, '\\b[A-Z]{2}\\d{3}\\b');`.

(`\b` is "word boundary")

`SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('AB3530A/AB476-1','\\b[A-Z]{2}\\d{3}\\b');` should return `'AB476'`

NB: instead of `[A-Z]`, which allows only for ASCII characters, you could use `\\p{Lu}`, which means “any character tagged as a letter by Unicode, and only the uppercase ones”. But I guess `[A-Z]` will be enough in your case.

Comment: Sxilderik, thanks a lot. That was what I was searching for, unfortunately it seems like MariaDB REGEXP_SUBSTR does not support it.

Comment: If your version of MariaDB is 10.0.5 at least, my edited answer should work.

Answer (score -1):

ShortDive!

Instead of Regex you can try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR('AB3530A/AB476-1',9,5) constant_length
     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('AB3530A/AB476-1','/',-1),'-',1) variable_length
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I am searching for as the string can vary and also the position of the string to be extract and signs as well. So I definitely want to use RegExp.

Comment: @ShortDive Then you are failing at creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Basically I am trying to extract the pattern 2 letters, 3 digits.
This pattern can occur everywhere, not only after specified signs.
Therefore the string could also look like this:
HG346A-TX/CG234-1-PVT (CG234 should be extracted) or like this ZT234P/EW345-4-34 (EW345 should be extracted).

Comment: @ShortDive edit the question and provide a clear reproducible example.